# Method to reset members inside groupBox

Tags: c#, reset, groupbox

is there any method for groupBox to clear all properties of objects inside groupBox. for example clear all textboxes, deselect all checkboxes etc. and set them to default. or i should code one by one to clear them? i want to do this on event listview SelectedIndexChanged.

Update:

ok thanks for replays, i found that you can select controls inside  groupbox very simple.

```
        foreach (Control ctrl in groupBox2.Controls)//this will only select controls of groupbox2
        {
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                (ctrl as TextBox).Text = "";
            }
            if (ctrl is CheckBox)
            {
                (ctrl as CheckBox).Checked = false;
            }
            if (ctrl is ComboBox)
            {
                (ctrl as ComboBox).SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
            //etc
        }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: ok thanks for innformation i wont do it next! @JohnSaunders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to do that is :

```
Control myForm = Page.FindControl("Form1");
foreach (Control ctrl in myForm.Controls)
{
    //Clears TextBox
    if (ctrl is System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)
    {
        (ctrl as TextBox).Text = "";
    }
    //Clears DropDown Selection
    if (ctrl is System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)
    {
         (ctrl as DropDownList).ClearSelection();
    }
    //Clears ListBox Selection
    if (ctrl is System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox)
    {
        (ctrl as ListBox).ClearSelection();
    }
    //Clears CheckBox Selection
    if (ctrl is System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)
    {
        (ctrl as CheckBox).Checked = false;
    }
    //Clears RadioButton Selection
    if (ctrl is System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList)
    {
        (ctrl as RadioButtonList).ClearSelection();
    }
    //Clears CheckBox Selection
    if (ctrl is System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList)
    {
        (ctrl as CheckBoxList).ClearSelection();
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no Page.FindControl() method. except in VisualStyleElement ? or i mistake something?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to clear all the controls inside the group box one by one.

Comment: ok. i wanted to make sure that there is no way before i write bunch of code you know. :)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make a function like this:

```
private void ClearControls(Control control)
{
    var textbox = control as TextBox;
    if (textbox != null)
        textbox.Text = string.Empty;

    var dropDownList = control as DropDownList;
    if (dropDownList != null)
        dropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;

    // And add any other controls
    // ...

    foreach( Control childControl in control.Controls )
    {
        ClearControl( childControl );
    }
}
```

Just call it like this:

```
ClearControls(this);
```

This will work recursively, so if you have any panels, for example, with their own set of controls to clear, this will clear those too.